# Making an ASP.NET code block only visible to Debugging/Development on .aspx front-end page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, debugging

*ASP.NET front-end .aspx page (hiding code when deployed).*

I'm trying to simply have a button for us developers that auto-fills this gigantic form, the only thing I've been able to find is this:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        <% If (Context.IsDebuggingEnabled) Then %>
            $('#fillForm').show().on('click', function () {
                // nothing special here, loops through items and fills them in
            });
        <% End If %>

        // other normal JS code here
    });
</script>
```

The problem is when the project is pushed into the *live* test environment, they still see the button! It starts out as: `display:none;`, and somehow this code is being hit even on when deployed!

**SOLUTION:: Thanks to @Icarus**
Test environment web.config also has

`<compilation debug="true">`

For it to work only within our development environment I had to do:

```
<% If (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Environment").ToUpper() = " DEVELOPMENT") Then %>
  // stuff here
<% End if %>
```

Comment: I don't see any code which generates the "#fillForm" button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means your `Web.config` in production still has `debug=true` in the compilation Section. You should always set the flag to `false` when deploying to Production. There's a performance hit, and it may expose more details about exceptions than one would want a user to be able to see.

Comment: There it is! Found out I need to test for something more specific to know it's our developer web.config: `If System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Environment").ToUpper() = "DEVELOPMENT" Then`

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS glad you got it working but you still should set the flag to false on Production environments.

Comment: Apparently we need it to get the stack track information from the testers, but we're going to look into it to make sure if that's neccessary anymore. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

According to what you state, the `Context.IsDebuggingEnabled` must be true in your live test environment.